# Can anything non-obvious go wrong with this Python trick?

Tags: python

I frequently want a dictionary mapping keys to consecutive IDs so I do the following:

```
ids = defaultdict()
ids.default_factory = ids.__len__
```

Is there anything strange that could go wrong due to the use of the `__len__` method here?

Comment: Why would you not use a list for this?

Comment: @rdas because OP doesn't want to look up by index, but the other thing.

Comment: @rdas for constant time access to ID by key.

Comment: `list.index()` is too slow? To me this violates the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @rdas later on I usually convert the `defaultdict` to a regular `dict`. This is for natural language processing work so the keys are either words or subword units.

Comment: OK, so today I learned that `defaultdict ` doesn't only return a default value if the key is not found, it also adds this key-value-pair to the dict. cool trick!

Comment: Does the value need to be unique? As if you do `ids['x']; ids['y']` then `del ids['x']` then `ids['x']` again... both x and y have a value of one...?

Comment: @JonClements Ah yeah that would be a problem, although I explicitly don't do that. The fact that it's necessary to not do that may be a good enough reason to just use a regular `dict` and a counter.

Comment: If unique is a harder requirement than consecutive, `ids.default_factory = id` could work too. But yeah, just use a real counter.

Comment: @DavisYoshida I've sometimes used the equivalent of: `ids = defaultdict(lambda c=itertools.count(): next(c))`...

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer They do need to be _fairly_ consecutive, as a missing value in my typical use case corresponds to one wasted row of a matrix.

Comment: @JonClements That seems robust to deletion which is an improvement, nice!

Comment: what about somebody just assigning a wrong id to an element? like ids['my_val'] = 3.14

Comment: @Davis does ordering matter... eg... if you have "one two three two" - does "one" have to be 1 and "two" has to be 2 and "three" has to be three because of the word ordering (so that'd be 1, 2, 3, 2), or would 2, 1, 3, 1 be fine as long as unique?

Comment: @ikamen That would be a problem with anything that's backed by a `dict`, but I suppose for maximum safety you could have something without `__setitem__`

Comment: @JonClements 2, 1, 3, 1 would be fine, but you'd need to know the number of keys beforehand to end up with something like that which seems unlikely.

Comment: @DavisYoshida Its a good idea to somehow document the intended API of your object, both for yourself and others

Comment: Yeah it's wrapped in a `make_id_defaultdict` method which has a docstring explaining its purpose.

Comment: @Davis I'm just thinking to ensure no gaps, you just accumulate all the words into a set... then once you're done adding stuff, you materialise it something like: `ids = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(my_set)`....

Comment: Yeah that'd be fine too. Sometimes I iteratively build up a vocab over a few calls to the same function though, so it's something like. `data1, vocab = f('path1', vocab=None)`, `data2, vocab = f('path', vocab=vocab)`. In this case the set thing is a bit more clunky, but if I'm just loading one chunk of data I often do something like that.

Comment: It's gonna break if you remove an item from dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too bad that you need to assign the default_factory each time. Maybe try something like this

```
class ConsecutiveIds(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConsecutiveIds, self)
        self.default_factory = lambda: len(self)

d = ConsecutiveIds()
```

There does seem to be an anomaly around deleting that will repeat old values

```
In [4]: d = ConsecutiveIds()

In [5]: d[0]
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: d[10]
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: d[20]
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: d
Out[8]: 
ConsecutiveIds(<function __main__.ConsecutiveIds.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>()>,
               {0: 0, 10: 1, 20: 2})

In [9]: del d[10]

In [10]: d[30]
Out[10]: 2

In [11]: d
Out[11]: 
ConsecutiveIds(<function __main__.ConsecutiveIds.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>()>,
               {0: 0, 20: 2, 30: 2})
```

That anomaly doesn't seem to be present in [ikamen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812873/633094), but more concisely, you could say:

```
class ConsecutiveIds(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConsecutiveIds, self)
        self.default_factory = self.next_int
        self.index = 0

    def next_int(self):
        result = self.index
        self.index += 1
        return result
```

This can be further refined as

```
class ConsecutiveIds(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConsecutiveIds, self)
        counter = itertools.count()
        self.default_factory = lambda: next(counter)
```

Comment: Accepted since it points out the problem with deletion in addition to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything strange that could go wrong due to the use of the
>   `__len__` method here?

Depends on the intended usage and restrictions. What is intended behavior to differentiate something going wrong from 'thats how python works'?

If what you want is an object giving consequential ids to other objects it 'registers', then here is a less surprising implementation:

```
class ConseqIds:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ctr = 0
        self.elements = {}

    def assign_next(self, obj):
        self.elements[obj] = self.ctr
        self.ctr += 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if not item in self.elements:
            self.assign_next(item)
        return self.elements[item]

ids = ConseqIds()
print(ids['first element'])
print(ids['second element'])
ids.assign_next('third element')
```

You will avoid many edge cases, and be sure on what it does.

Comment: Even though this is incredibly verbose I'm just going to upvote this one because I don't think one should code-golf this sort of stuff for sure.

Comment: The many edge cases is what the question was about originally. It seems that deletion is the main one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with it but you should make it a bit more self explanatory.  Perhaps using a lambda:

```
ids = defaultdict()
ids.default_factory = lambda:len(ids)
```